# How to launch an EXE as an argument in java, but still with parameters

Tags: java

I'm in a situation where I need to launch a .exe, but I meed to launch it with parameters, AND it needs to be launched as an argument itself, but cant be launched from a command line. I need to launch javaw itself, with my exe as an argument. For example:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe" -jar "PATH/TO/.exe"
```

However, `"PATH/TO/.exe"` needs `-arg1` and `-arg2`. Placing the parameters inside of the path leads to java not finding them, whereas placing them outside leads to java thinking they belong to itself and trying to use them.

EDIT: I am running the exe with java because I am using a completely different program to start all this. I cannot use a different java program, all I have to work with is the target box. It is designed to start exe's, but I need to run the exe through java. ALL I have to use is the path area where you would usually type where the exe is located.

Comment: Why are you trying to use Java to run an `.exe`?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish.  Can you try to explain a bit clearer.  What is "PATH/TO/.exe" doing?  Does it get executed before javaw.exe?  or is it passed as an argument to your jar?

Comment: Does that mean you're trying to pass the command to another Java program?  `javaw.exe` won't run a Windows executable

Answer (score 0):

The basic trick is:

```
try {
    final Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(ARRAY_OF_EXE_AND_ARGUMENTS);
    if (p == null) {
        // some error
        // probably command not found, abort.
    }

    try {
        final int retval = p.exitValue();
        if (retval == 0) {
            // Process ended immediately.
            // Probably a problem, abort.

        } else {
            // Process crashed, abort.

        }
    } catch (final IllegalThreadStateException itse) {
        // Process is running.
        // all is good
    }
} catch (final IOException e) {
    // Error running exe, abort.
}
```

Where `ARRAY_OF_EXE_AND_ARGUMENTS` is a String array, where first is path to the executable, and following are it's command-line arguments.

To pass the exe and argumetns to java, this is the common pattern:

```
java -jar MyJar.jar "/path/to/virus.exe argument1 argument2"
```

And then you split it by space or something.

Comment: `ProcessBuilder` would be a preferred solution, as it allows you to redirect output, change the execution context and handels parameters with spaces better